# Invoking Message driven bean via SOAPUI?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I started working on an existing project and want to test the changes I did on a Message driven bean. But I never used message driven beans, so how do I invoke this bean? Is it possible to invoke it via SOAPUI call? 
Bean code :

```
    @MessageDriven(name = "StudentsScores", activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationStudents", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queue/returns")
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "sendResponse", propertyValue = "true"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "dbPassword", propertyValue = "stud_db")
})
public class StudentScoreListener {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can do that by using Hermes JMS. You can use it as a standalone util or integrate into SoapUI. For more details refer to [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/jms/getting-started.html)